# css-grid: image takes to much space inside grid

Tags: css, image, css-grid

I have a layout with a centered content column where I want an image to break out on the right side to the edge of the browser. Without an image it works fine, but with an image and a breakpoint with fixed values for the cols 2 and 3, the image takes too much space.

```
.copy{
  grid-row-start: 1;
  grid-column-start: 2;
  grid-column-end: 3;
}

.img{
  grid-row-start: 1;
  grid-column-start: 3;
  grid-column-end: 5;
  width: 100%;
}

.grid-container-centered {
  wodth: 100%;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 5% 45% 45% 5%;
}

// now it starts breaking with an image
@media (min-width: 1280px) {
  .grid-container-centered {
    grid-template-columns: auto 576px 576px auto; // 576px => 1280*0.9 / 2
  }
}
```

[image]

I have created a demo there https://codepen.io/destroy90210/pen/OJbJQby?editors=1100

**Solution**
Instead of "auto" it must be "1fr"

```
grid-template-columns: 1fr 576px 576px 1fr;
```

Comment: 1fr instead of auto if you expect to have the same space on each side. different `auto` aren't equal but will behave differently and will have different sizes

Comment: thank's it works :) I was thinking auto is filling automatic the remaining space :)